# WebService to Stored Procedure with XML response to WebService with DS.GETXML change < to &LT

Tags: c#, sql-server, webservice-client

Step 1. SQL Server Procedure Result

```
SELECT RoomIDX FROM TableName FOR XML PATH('ROOM')
```

Step 2. WebService receiving as Dataset and convert to XML before sending to client

```
string s = o.DBMethod(RequestString).GetXml().ToString();
```

Step 3a: If Response from Procedure is without XML then all is ok 
Step 3b: If Response from Procedure is XML like Step 1 I got this response

```
<NewDataSet>
<Table>
<Column1>lt;ROOMgt;lt;RoomIDxgt;1lt;/RoomIDxgt;lt;/ROOMgt;</Column1>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

I removed the & character to show properly. 
I need to know how to fix this issue.

Comment: See Wiki for special characters in XML and HTML.  You can use in c# System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) to convert html special characters.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: You are taking XML returned from SQL Result and encode to XML again. Question is why do you want to encode XML twice? Try removing ".GetXML()"

Comment: This service owned by other. I cant do anything.

Comment: Why do you need to specifically return XML of 1 table?